# Why is this program freezing when I use these loops?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm an extreme beginner at Visual Basic and I'm trying to make a simple 4 question quiz with radio buttons and a label that allows a user to select an answer to the question being presented and then recording how many questions they answer correctly. I decided to use loops to count which question the user is on, and how many they have answered correctly. I must be missing something obvious here, because when I click the button to initiate this code, the program completely freezes.

What am I doing wrong? (apologies if this is too vague of a question)

```
Private Sub QuizButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles QuizButton1.Click
        Dim question As Integer = 0
        Dim correct As Integer = 0
        Do Until question = 4

            While question = 0
                QuizLabel1.Text = "How much force do the Great Horned Owl's talons put out while clenched? A. 28 pounds B. 13 pounds C. 200 pounds D. 20 pounds"
                If Abutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 1
                    correct = correct + 1
                ElseIf Bbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 1
                ElseIf Cbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 1
                ElseIf Dbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 1
                End If
            End While
            While question = 1
                QuizLabel1.Text = "What's a nickname for the Great Horned Owl? A. Lion Owl B. Tiger Owl C. Hawk Owl D. Cat Owl "
                If Abutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 2
                ElseIf Bbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 2
                    correct = correct + 1
                ElseIf Cbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 2
                ElseIf Dbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 2
                End If
            End While
            While question = 2
                QuizLabel1.Text = "Why is this owl called 'Horned'? A. It has small horns B. It has pointy ears C. Common folklore D. It has feathery tufts on its head"
                If Abutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 3
                ElseIf Bbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 3

                ElseIf Cbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 3
                ElseIf Dbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 3
                    correct = correct + 1
                End If

            End While
            While question = 3
                QuizLabel1.Text = "What's the maximum recorded length of a Great Horned Owl? A. 20.4 inches B. 15.8 inches C. 12.3 inches D. 24.8 inches"
                If Abutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 4
                ElseIf Bbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 4

                ElseIf Cbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 4
                ElseIf Dbutton1.Checked Then
                    question = 4
                    correct = correct + 1
                End If
            End While
        Loop
        Dim score As Integer
        score = correct * 25
        QuizLabel1.Text = "Thanks for taking the quiz! You scored a " & score & "%. Press the button below to play again."
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your code goes into circular looping which does not end that's why it freezes

Comment: You need to exit *QuizButton1_Click* to proceed in other operations on your form like clicking buttons and such.

Comment: What specifically could I do to the code to stop it from infinitely looping? And how would I exit QuizButton1_Click?

Comment: Why loop at all? Use an If statement or Case

Comment: Good point, I guess there's no real reason to loop. However, would there be a way to avoid this happening even if I still used loops?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?`...if you really want to learn why it's doing what it's doing (and you should if you're a beginner), set a breakpoint at `Private Sub QuizButton1_Click` and click it. Then use F8 to step thru the code line by line. You'll see exactly why it's freezing. It's going to go into the Do loop and then into the first While loop and then it will just keep looping. And the UI will freeze as it's looping not allowing you to do anything. And it won't process any other UI messages...no button clicks, no checkbox clicks, etc...until it exits that loop.

Comment: Okay thanks, Ken White. Remember, you could have saved even more time by simply not reading the question and leaving a comment. And I certainly won't be using this website anymore because of it's absurd pretentiousness and total hostility to beginner questions

Comment: @davidib17 - Do hang around. Stack Overflow can come across as pretentious, but that's because we strive for quality questions and answers. You'll find this a very useful resource.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a VB expert, but I may be able to offer some help here. If I had to guess I would say that your program is locking up because it is in an endless loop. I think the loop is continuously evaluating and is not allowing for anything else. I would use an event handler, and trigger evaluation when the user clicks the answer. It looks like you have an event handler to start the quiz, but then the loops take over. I am not sure exactly what you layout is, but I am using buttons for your a,b,c and d awnsers. When you click the button it trigers an event and is processed accordingly. I tried to make this easy to understand. There is more elegant ways to acomplish this, but this will work. Try somthing like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim question As Integer
    Dim correct As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        correct = 0
        Label2.Text = correct

        Abutton1.Hide()
        Bbutton1.Hide()
        Cbutton1.Hide()
        Dbutton1.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub QuizButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles QuizButton1.Click
        question = 0
        QuizLabel1.Text = "How much force do the Great Horned Owl's talons put out while clenched? A. 28 pounds B. 13 pounds C. 200 pounds D. 20 pounds"
        QuizButton1.Hide()
        Abutton1.Show()
        Bbutton1.Show()
        Cbutton1.Show()
        Dbutton1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Abutton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Abutton1.Click
        test(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Bbutton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bbutton1.Click
        test(2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Cbutton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cbutton1.Click
        test(3)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Dbutton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Dbutton1.Click
        test(4)
    End Sub

    Private Sub test(button)

        Select Case question
            Case 0
                If button = 1 Then
                    correct = correct + 1
                    Label2.Text = correct
                End If

                question = question + 1
                QuizLabel1.Text = "What's a nickname for the Great Horned Owl? A. Lion Owl B. Tiger Owl C. Hawk Owl D. Cat Owl "
            Case 1
                If button = 1 Then
                    correct = correct + 1
                    Label2.Text = correct
                End If

                question = question + 1
                QuizLabel1.Text = "What's a nickname for the Great Horned Owl? A. Lion Owl B. Tiger Owl C. Hawk Owl D. Cat Owl "
            Case 2
                If button = 4 Then
                    correct = correct + 1
                    Label2.Text = correct
                End If

                question = question + 1
                QuizLabel1.Text = "Why is this owl called 'Horned'? A. It has small horns B. It has pointy ears C. Common folklore D. It has feathery tufts on its head"
        End Select

    End Sub

End Class
```